# Convert dictionary with integer keys to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary defined as follows:

```
>>> mydict = {0:obj0,5:obj1,4:obj3,7:obj4}
```

The dictionary has integer as keys.

I am trying to convert this dict to a numpy array.

so that:

```
>>> nparray[[4,0]] = [obj3,obj0]
>>> nparray[[7,4]] = [obj4,obj3]
```

I am aware of numpy structured arrays but unfortunately it seems like **integer** indexes must correspond to the position in the array as opposed to the key. Is there a way to change this behavior.

I was considering a way to "trick" the numpy array. For example instead of reading [4,0] it reads the rows corresponding to those keys.

My end goal is to have some sort of custom class that inherits from np.ndarray, if there isn't another alternative.

**UPDATE**

A bit more background, I originally solved this problem by using the class below, which stores the objects:

```
class MyArray (dict):
    def __init__ (self,*args):
        dict.__init__(self,*args)
    def __getitem__ (self, key):
        if not hasattr (key, '__iter__'):
            return dict.__getitem__ (self,key)
        return List([dict.__getitem__ (self,k) for k in key])
```

Which allows multi-key indexes.
The key array can be very huge (1000000+), and so **for k in key** can take a long time and/or be expensive. I wanted to use numpy arrays to take advantage of it's speed, lower memory etc.. and wouldn't have to use that for loop.
Is it still warranted?

Comment: Is there a good reason to do so? Numpy is designed for numerical computing. There is usually no points in filling a numpy array with strings or general objects.

Comment: You're thinking of your data in a fundamentally key-value-oriented way, while NumPy arrays are big multidimensional grids. It doesn't sound like you *want* a big multidimensional grid, in which case NumPy isn't going to solve your problems. Alternatively, if you do want a big multidimensional grid, what should go in all those cells the dict doesn't specify values for?

Comment: Good point julien, I really like how np arrays can take a list as input to take items. And also because its fast and doesn't take that much memory compared to a list. The objects contain attributes and wnat to be able to do nparray[[4,0]].someattr and get a list of attributes. The values would be numbers, and i would also like them to be numpy arrays

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at `pandas` (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/). In particular, see the pandas `DataFrame`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe

Comment: You can make an array with references to your objects, but `array[[0, 4]]` is going to return an array so when you do `array[[0, 4]].someattr` you're going to get an attribute error. You'll end up doing something like `[i.someattr for i in array[[0, 4]]]` ...

Comment: Yep, Rico, that was my plan. I have a custom list class that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets make the dictionary; here my `obj` are tuples (just for convenience):

```
In [563]: mydict={0:(0,),5:(1,),4:(3,),7:(4,)}
In [564]: mydict
Out[564]: {0: (0,), 4: (3,), 5: (1,), 7: (4,)}
```

Initial an array that's big enough and dtype=object:

```
In [565]: A=np.empty((8,),dtype=object)    
In [566]: A
Out[566]: array([None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

copy values from `mydict` to `A`, using the key as the array index:

```
In [567]: for k in mydict:
   .....:     A[k]=mydict[k]
   .....:     

In [568]: A
Out[568]: array([(0,), None, None, None, (3,), (1,), None, (4,)], dtype=object)

In [574]: A[[4,0]]
Out[574]: array([(3,), (0,)], dtype=object)
In [575]: A[[7,4]]
Out[575]: array([(4,), (3,)], dtype=object)
```

Items defined in the dictionary now appear in the corresponding slots in the array.  I won't make any claims about this being useful.

---

I could mask the `nones`.

```
In [581]: Am=np.ma.masked_array(A)
In [582]: Am.mask=[False,True,True,True,False,False,True,False]

In [583]: Am
Out[583]: 
masked_array(data = [(0,) -- -- -- (3,) (1,) -- (4,)],
             mask = [False  True  True  True False False  True False],
       fill_value = ?)
```

The `nones` are still there, just 'hidden'.  I don't know if masking does anything useful with object types.

---

### Subclass dict

From comments it sounds like the main thing you want is the ability to select multiple items from a dictionary, something akin to the array `A[[0,3,5]]` indexing.

It might be easier to subclass `dict` than to expand or subclass `np.ndarray`.

`scipy.sparse` has a sparse matrix format which is a subclass of dict.  It's `__getitem__` may give ideas on how to extend your own dict.  I'll try to come up with a simpler version.

In mean time, one way to fetch a group of keys is with an expression like:

```
In [646]: {k:mydict[k] for k in mydict if k in {0,4}}
Out[646]: {0: (0,), 4: (3,)}
```

or simpler

```
In [647]: {k:mydict[k] for k in [0,4]}
Out[647]: {0: (0,), 4: (3,)}
```

but more robust:

```
In [649]: {k:mydict.get(k,None) for k in [0,4,5,10]}
Out[649]: {0: (0,), 4: (3,), 5: (1,), 10: None}
```

Comment: If i really want to implement things the way i want, this seems like the only feasible option. Is there any issues that can be cause by those empty elements? The ids usually 6 digits and don't have order. So that might be an issue. I guess i should look at other ways to implement that to not involve numpy

Comment: One way or other you have to decide what to do about the 'empty' elements.  Do they represent 0, not valid entries (masked), or what?  There is a `scipy.sparse` module that represents arrays with lots of zeros, but it can't handle 'objects', just real numbers.  And one of it's formats is a dictionary like yours.

Comment: Another option is to subclass dictionary, so it accepts a list or tuple of keys, returning a portion of itself.  `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix` class has such a `__getitem__` extension.

Comment: This solution is very similar to what i did, see above update

Comment: boxes1[b]=boxes[b]  
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices